# How do I check if zoom.exe is still running and if it is I want to kill it

Tags: batch-file

How do I check if `Zoom.exe` is still running and then if its running I want to kill it in batch scripting below is my code which isn't working, it does print that `Process not running`

```
QPROCESS "zoom.exe">NUL
IF (%ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0) (ECHO "Process running" & TASKKILL /F /IM "Zoom.exe") ELSE (ECHO "Process not running")
```

Comment: it says `Process not running` even tho I'm using it

Comment: You don't even have to check, if the process is running before killing it.

Comment: oh but I want to check if its running or not

Comment: Then you can look for already answered questions on that issue, as well.

Comment: that is what I found on previous questions I found that code from a question but for some reason idk why it jumps to the else part of it

Comment: You shouldn't use invalid syntax. Read the help of `IF /?´

Comment: okay I checked the `if /?` and edited my code but now it says ```ERROR: Invalid argument/option - 'ELSE'.
Type "TASKKILL /?" for usage.``` sorry for dumb questions I'm new to batch scripting

Comment: Sure I'll check that and thanks for helping me

Comment: You are comparing `(%errorlevel%` with `0)`. `(0` will never be equal to `0)`

Comment: So you read the help and still decided to leave the parentheses in their for the comparison?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```batch-file
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "imgname=Zoom.exe"
set "opt=tokens=* delims="
echo:
set /a "count=0"
for /f "%opt%" %%i in ('tasklist /fi "imagename eq !imgname!" /fi "status eq running"') do (
    echo %%i
    set /a "count+=1"
)
set /a "count-=2"
echo:
echo There are !count! !imgname! processes running.
echo:
if "!count!" gtr "0" (call taskkill /f /fi "imagename eq !imgname!")
endlocal
```

EDIT:

some explanation, but it is very easy. Also, to better understand yourself, type `tasklist /?` and `taskkill /?` and check @Mofi 's suggestions.

Basically, with the `for /f` loop you "read" (end `echo`, as when normally calling a command) the output of a command (passed within `' '`).

Meanwhile you count the output lines with `set /a "count+=1"`. This is done since in this case the output format is somehow "fixed". So you cannot extend this sentence to other commands. That is, `tasklist` command is at least 2 lines (in case process is not running, try with a non-existent imagename for example), or more. If more, it means that process is running, so to count how many you take out first two lines (yes, still 2 lines, but with different information w.r.t. process not running, this is why in this case this works) i.e. `set /a "count-=2"`.

At this point you only need to check how many lines you left in the output. If 0, no process is running, else, you kill it/them.

Comment: I understand it now, thanks for helping me!

Comment: You're welcome. If this solves your problem/question, it is good practice to accept the answer as a solution. Have a nice day :)